# Spark creates extra partitions inside partition

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I have a Spark program that reads the data from text file as RDD and convert into Parquet file using spark-sql and partitioned using a single partitionkey. Once in a while instead of creating one partition it creates two partitions that is a partition inside a partition.

My data is partitioned on date and the output folder is in s3://datalake/intk/parquetdata.

After the Spark job is run I am seeing output as :

```
s3://datalake/intk/parquetdata/datekey=102018/a.parquet
s3://datalake/intk/parquetdata/datekey=102118/a.parquet
s3://datalake/intk/parquetdata/datekey=102218/datekey=102218/a.parquet
```

Code snippet:

```scala
val savepath = "s3://datalake/intk/parquetdata/"
val writeDF = InputDF.write
  .mode(savemode)
  .partitionBy(partitionKey)
  .parquet(savePath)
```

I am running my Spark job in EMR cluster version 5.16, Spark version 2.2, Scala version 2.11 and the output location is s3. I am not sure why this behavior takes place and I don't see this issue following any pattern and this partition occurs only once in a while.

Comment: Looks like you are using `s3://datalake/intk/parquetdata/datekey=102218/` as `savePath` while keeping `.partitionBy`. If you want to write to specific partition directly drop the partition column and omit `.partitionBy`

Comment: Sorry i have edited the post now, my savepath is  "s3://datalake/intk/parquetdata" i am not specifying any datekey in my savepath